# Apache OSGI Karaf's features-maven-plugin:create-kar is failing on a features.xml bundle using the PAX wrap/bnd syntax

Tags: java, maven, osgi, apache-karaf, pax-runner

The problematic line is the first *bundle* in this features snippet

```
<feature name="stuff-common-security">
    <bundle>wrap:mvn:org.springframework/ldap/1.3.0.RELEASE,mvn:com.mycompany.stuff/stuff-common-security/1.0-SNAPSHOT/bnd/spring-ldap</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:org.springframework.security/spring-security-core/3.1.0.RELEASE</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:org.springframework.security/spring-security-ldap/3.1.0.RELEASE</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:com.mycompany.stuff/stuff-common-security/1.0-SNAPSHOT</bundle>
</feature>
```

The create-kar goal fails with this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.karaf.tooling:features-maven-plugin:2.2.9:create-kar (create-kar) on project stuff-demo:
 Failed to create kar archive: 
 Could not find artifact org.springframework:ldap:stuff-common-security:1.0-SNAPSHOT:1.3.0.RELEASE,mvn:com.mycompany.stuff 
in maven.mycompany.com (http://maven.mycompany.com/artifactory/libs-release-local)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Try downloading the file manually from the project website.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Then, install it using the command:
[ERROR] mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.springframework -DartifactId=ldap 
       -Dversion=1.3.0.RELEASE,mvn:com.mycompany.stuff -Dclassifier=1.0-SNAPSHOT 
       -Dpackaging=stuff-common-security -Dfile=/path/to/file
```

It seems to be misparsing that bundle element text and treating the wrapper as part of the version number.

```
<bundle>wrap:mvn:org.springframework/ldap/1.3.0.RELEASE,mvn:com.mycompany.stuff/stuff-common-security/1.0-SNAPSHOT/bnd/spring-ldap</bundle>
```

Karaf itself is happy as a clam with this bundle syntax, so I don't think I made an error there.

Is there an alternative way I can express this so I don't get this error from create-kar?

Comment: +1 Karaf is happy as a clam :D That brings joy to my heart after wanting to strangle it for the past few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping the comma with a '\' or using a CDATA section (I had some escaping issues noted on [mailing list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/karaf-user/201212.mbox/%3C891B68CE-64CE-44D9-919B-70AD63A0F7E4@gmail.com%3E)):

```
<bundle><![CDATA[
wrap:mvn:org.springframework/ldap/1.3.0.RELEASE,mvn:com.mycompany.stuff/stuff-common-security/1.0-SNAPSHOT/bnd/spring-ldap
]]></bundle>
```

If that doesn't work - I'd suspect the plugin is not using actual URL handlers and is just stripping off the `wrap` protocol, so would suggest [filing a bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KARAF)

As you're using classifiers you might want to just do the embed in the pom for `stuff-common-security` but that might make your build a bit too hairy =]

If so create a maven module with only those two modules as dependencies then use the BND/maven-bundle-plugin's [embed dependencies](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html#ApacheFelixMavenBundlePlugin%28BND%29-Embeddingdependencies) to merge them.